# Reference on projective space

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, projective-space

Given $V$ a finite dimensional vector space we could consider $\mathbb{P}(V)$ with its classical topology given by the quotient map $V\setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{P}(V)$ that assigns to a vector its line. Choosing coordinates in $V$ it's easy to endow to $\mathbb{P}(V)$ a smooth manifold structure. I'm looking for a reference on the coordinate free version of this differentiable structure. I'm aware that this construction uses hyperplanes $H$ to construct an atlas for $\mathbb{P}(V)$ that go from lines $\ell$ such that $\ell + H = V$ to euclidean space.

Answer (score 0):

You might find the following books useful:

1. [Tu](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781441973993)
2. [Naber](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781441972538)
3. [Rudolph & Schmidt](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9789400753440)